# Change font on iOS leftBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, fonts, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Appearance protocol only changes font of navbar's title.

iOS 5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use the appearance protocol for UIBarButtonItem for the UINavigationBar tree:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItemProxy = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:
    [UINavigationBar class], [UINavigationController class], nil];

NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{
    UITextAttributeFont : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f],
    UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowColor : [UIColor blackColor],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset : [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, -1.0f)]
};
[barButtonItemProxy setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: This does not seem to be limited to the leftBarButtonItem only, but rather styles both left and right barButtonItems.